Miller-Rabin primality test strong liar probability
This might be an old topic.
It is said that the probability a number is a strong liar to a composite number is less than 1/4 for one round of Miller-Rabin test, but I found it to be far less, especially for larger numbers.
I took the first 100 million 9 digit odd numbers (from 100000001 to 299999999).  After removing 10490870 prime numbers, and 76174138 composites that can be divided by small primes up to 101, I send the remaining 13334992 composites to one round of MR test using base 2.  Only 250 passed the test (strong liars).  That means base 2 is a strong liar to only 250 out of 13334992 composites.  That's far less than 1 in 4.
I repeated the same process for the first 100 million 10 digit odd numbers (1000000001 to 1199999999), and 2 is a strong liar for 83 out of 14218822 composites tested (again, removing any that has prime factors 101 or less).  And when I used 11, 12, 13, and 14 digit numbers, 2 is a liar for just 27, 5, 4, and 1 out of 15 to 17 million composites.  From 15 to 26 digits odd numbers, 2 is not a liar to any of the 17 to 20 million composites tested.
I know the first 100 million 15 digit odd numbers are a tiny portion of all.  But out of all the 17 million composites that do not have a prime factor 101 or less, 2 is not a liar to any of them.  That's quite different from the roughly less than 1 in 4 are liars.
Any one has a similar experience?

Two things: first of all, the random variable in the probability is the base, not the composite number. Second, the proof only gives an upper bound on the probability, it doesn't say anything about a lower bound

The Wikipedia article is pretty good here. The short version, however is that there are 2 closely related but different concepts. The first is what fraction of uniformly chosen composite numbers will be eliminated by a k randomly chosen bases. The second is for the numbers which are most resistant to Miller-Rabin, what percent of a values will determine that they are composite.
For the average case, much stronger bounds exist, but for the worst case 1/4 is about as good as we can do.

So most composites are detected quicker than you hoped, but you need to assume that you ran into a highly resistant one. And a probability of 1/4 means on average you perform 4/3 tests. The average number cannot be less than one so you don’t gain much.
